# difference between GetDesktopWindow() and HWND_DESKTOP

Tags: winapi

There's a win32 api function, [`GetDesktopWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504.aspx), which returns a handle of desktop window.

And there's another one - `HWND_DESKTOP` macro. I couldn't find official information in MSDN, but it's found in WinUser.h

```
#define HWND_DESKTOP        ((HWND)0)
```

So, what's difference between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HWND_DESKTOP` is only used by `MapWindowRect()` to indicate using screen coordinates, [as documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll notice its value is equal to NULL, which is also listed there. I'm guessing `HWND_DESKTOP` came first.

Of course, valid windows cannot be NULL for real, so `HWND_DESKTOP` isn't the handle of the desktop window. While I don't know of any real good things you can do with it, the proper way to get the desktop window's handle is with that function.

(For what it's worth, the example for `GetDesktopWindow()` uses the returned handle to position a dialog box on screen. I don't know if the current preference is to use the current monitor's work area instead...)